# Installing MySQL 5.1

Tags: installation, mysql

this question is surely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632056/how-do-you-install-mysql-5-1-on-ubuntu-8-10

Since I can't comment on that one...I am starting a new one. I'm having the same problem as the previous OP and I followed the answer provided by Andrew (the first answer with 2 vote ups) and added the repo.:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org lenny all
```

did a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then a

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
```

But still I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... 
Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable 
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or 
been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the 
situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: mysql-server-5.1 from the Synaptic Package
Depends: mysql-client-5.1 (>= 5.1.58-1~dotdeb.0) but it is not going to be
installed Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installable 
Recommends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not installable 
E: Broken packages
```

I have also located the mysql-server-5.1 from the synaptic package manager and tried to update the package from there but I still get the following error:

```
mysql-server-5.1:
 Depends: mysql-client-5.1 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libdbi-perl  but it is not installable
 Recommends: libhtml-template-perl  but it is not installable
```

**Edit:**

The contents of the sources.list file after adding the dotdeb repo.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release i386 (20110427.1)]/ natty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org lenny all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org lenny all
```

I'm having problems installing alomost every package like the openJDK, Skype ....:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version from dotdeb.org is horribly outdated, Ubuntu Natty does already have the MySQL server package in the repositories.

I suggest you to remove the last three `deb` and `deb-src` lines which are not added by default:

- `extras.ubuntu.com`: as of now, no packages for natty are available from that repo. This will only introduce a delay on updating your packages lists since it must still be fetched
- `archive.canonical.com lucid partner`: lucid? You're running Natty and already have a partner repo for Natty.
- `packages.dotdeb.org`: these packages are made for Debian and might not be compatible with Ubuntu

Please fix that, refresh your package lists (`sudo apt-get update`) and try to install MySQL again:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: I tried that first but I got the same `E: broken packages error`. So I searched SO and found one possible solution by adding the dotdeb.org repo. If I don't add the dotdeb repo, I even can't see the mysql-server-5.1 package on the Synaptic Package Manager. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question?

Comment: Pls see the edits. I've added the contents to the question.

Comment: It's very likely that the dotdeb repo is causing issues with MySQL. Could you remove the three repos as described?

Comment: Well, I removed the repos as you suggested but its still not working but I appreciate your help. But still, I'm in utter dismay and I've decided that it should go to the System Admin dept.

Comment: @newUbuntuUser: look for files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for obsolete sources list too.